# How to check efficiently two list of dictionary items in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-loops

I have two lists:

l1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":"pqr"}, {"a":3, "b":6, "c":"pir"}, {"a":2, "b":4, "c":""}]

l2 = [{"a":1, "b":3, "c":"def"}, {"a":2, "b":7, "c":"xyz"}]

I want to compare l1_item['a'] with l2_item['a']. If they match then I want to print l2_item['c']

I have used nested for loop to check each list of dictionary and then compare the value of l1_item['a'] with l2_item['a'].

[image: nested loop]

I want to know if there is any other efficient way to check it without using nested for loop. I am having time complexity issue for larger data sets.

Comment: Is `[item['a'] for item in list_1]` (and the same for second list) a unique sequence?

Comment: The order may get changed. I just need to check if item exists to any key value pair and then print another value of key.

Comment: Let me rephrase, can two items with `{'a': 1}` coexist in `list_1`? If no, then see dict solution below. If yes for both lists, then dict is not suitable.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Correct (but it's about `l2`, not `l1`). You could still use the dictionary approach but you would need to change it to use a list of items.

Comment: It still takes a lot of time as for loops are used multiple times here. I have to wait for a very long time when the list contains around 35 to 40 times of data in it. 
I printed the execution time and looks like it was less using nested for loop.
Note: There won't be any repetition of item['a']

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary for the lookup where the value of the a-item is the key.

```
l1 = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "pqr"}, {"a": 3, "b": 6, "c": "pir"},
      {"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": ""}]
l2 = [{"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "def"}, {"a": 2, "b": 7, "c": "xyz"}]

lookup = {item['a']: item for item in l2}
for entry in l1:
    item = lookup.get(entry['a'])
    if item:
        print(item['c'])
```

You need to create the dictionary once with O(n), but accessing it afterwards is O(1).

---

If the value of *a* could be in `l2` more than once you will have to keep a list of items in the lookup dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "pqr"}, {"a": 3, "b": 6, "c": "pir"},
      {"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": ""}]
l2 = [{"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "def"}, {"a": 2, "b": 7, "c": "xyz"}, {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "uvw"}, ]

lookup = defaultdict(list)
for item in l2:
    lookup[item['a']].append(item)

for entry in l1:
    items = lookup.get(entry['a'])
    if items:
        for item in items:
            print(item['c'])
```

This will give you

```
def
uvw
xyz
```